# Question was flagged and deleted, but reputation not restored

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, flags, deleted-questions

I have asked a question that got 1 downvote, and I have flagged it for deletion, since I have accepted that it is not formatted well for an SE question.

In my profile, this question is now listed among deleted questions. But I didn't get the reputation restored (from 1 downvote). Why is this so? Doesn't a deleted question restore the reputation as it was before the question was asked? Thank you.

Comment: It may take a while... probably up to ten minutes for you to get the rep back.

Comment: @hichris123 - I found that out. But I have asked my question days ago.

Comment: @hichris123: Really? In my only experience with this, I didn't get the 2 rep back...(until I did something else, at which point I really didn't care anymore.) Vaguely curious about any reasoning behind the design nevertheless...

Comment: The reputation on your rep tab all adds up just right, and you don't have any question with exactly one downvote.  Either you did get the rep back and were mistaken that you didn't, or one of the two un-deleted posts you have is the one that you think is deleted.

Comment: @Servy - My post refers to a question on SuperUser SE. There, my question was flagged ( by me ) and deleted - on the bottom of the question page is even a moderator's name who deleted the question. My mistake would be a possible explanation. But my reputation there is low and doesn't change often, so I can keep track of it ( I know what rep I had before ). Now I have 28, before I had 33. Also, I keep track of the rep changes notifications, and no notification appeared. I just lost 5 rep due to that question deletion.

Comment: @JamesC Your reputation matches the actions on your account.  If you lost rep when the question was deleted then odds are the question has some upvotes to go with those downvotes, so deleting it was a net loss in rep.

Comment: @JamesC Do you have the "show removed posts" box checked at the bottom of your reputation history? It should show you exactly how much you gained or lost from the deletion.

Comment: @animuson I do, and I see the -2 +2 there. That must be it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [your reputation page](https://superuser.com/users/278408/james-c?tab=reputation):

[image: downvote removed]

Note that *when you have the appropriate checkbox checked* you'll see both the reputation lost to the downvote and regained from the deletion.

If you don't check it, you won't see either.

Either way, you're not seeing a reputation loss that isn't explained.

Comment: Thank you. What kind of reputation loss can stay unexplained though ?

Comment: Off the top of my head? There's a bug floating around with retracted upvotes that'll cause you to hit the reputation cap at 198 instead of 200 in certain scenarios. Not something most folks need to worry about though.